# Dual forms authentication in asp.net 2.0 - 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, formsauthenticationticket

**BACKGROUND**

I have two websites under the same domain. One website encapsulates Login/Account Management functions only and the other website is the real website.

- **LoginWeb** - only Login Page/css/images/javascript folder allow anonymous access
- **AdminWebsite** - completely locked down via forms auth. i.e not even javascript/images/css folders have `<authorization><allow users=*>`

**WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE**
This is the workflow I am trying to achieve and have accomplished 99% of it :

1. If the user hits any page on **AdminWebsite** he is sent back to **LoginWeb** by FormsAuthentication
2. User supplies credentials in the loginpage and **LoginWeb** website issues a forms auth ticket. User is still not logged into **AdminWebSite** yet. (This way user can go to changepassword page etc and do account management functions)
3. User goes to two more steps in **LoginWeb** and now can be issued the FormsAuth ticket for **AdminWebsite** and redirected to it.

**99% IS ALREADY WORKING**
This is the code in LoginWeb which tries to issue the FormsAuth ticket for AdminWeb, but it is not working. i.e AdminWeb is still redirecting me back to Login. I am sure there is something very trivial I am missing but I can't figure out what exactly it is?????????

```
public void SetAuthenticationTicket(string username)
{
    MachineKeySection sec=(MachineKeySection)WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("").SectionGroups["system.web"].Sections["machineKey"]; 
    FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        username,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
        false, //true or false
        sec.DecryptionKey, //Custom data like your webkey can go here
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    var encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
    var cookie = new HttpCookie("ADMINWEB", encryptedTicket)
    {
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
        Domain = "xxx.com"
    };
    Response.AppendCookie(cookie);
}
```

---

These are my web.config sections for Forms Auth:

**LoginWeb**

```
  <machineKey validationKey="XXXXXX" decryptionKey="XXX" validation="SHA1"/>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="LoginWeb"
            domain="xxx.com"
            loginUrl="~/account/Logon"
            timeout="1440"
            cookieless="UseCookies"
            slidingExpiration="false"
            protection="All"
            path="/"/>
  </authentication>
```

**AdminWebSite**

```
   <machineKey validationKey="XXXXXX" decryptionKey="XXX" validation="SHA1"/>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="ADMINWEB"
            domain="xxx.com"
            loginUrl="http://loginweb/account/Logon"
            timeout="1440"
            cookieless="UseCookies"
            slidingExpiration="false"
            protection="All"
            path="/"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Comment: This is for Turnkey and others...Very interesting thing. Contrary to common sense, if I remove the Domain = "xxx.com" line in the SetAuthenticationTicket() function, it magically starts working. I am testing this on localhost however, so it could be something to do with that, but it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: That might be the key since localhost client would request tickets for the localhost domain from the browser.  Maybe compare it to the ticket that is created for the LOGINWEB.

Answer (score 0):

This site, [Forms Authentication Across Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc.aspx), implies that the Name on the forms attribute should be the same.

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I am trying to achieve. Both sites are already working fine using Forms Auth (i.e using the same name in the forms element like you are saying. But I am trying to NOT DO THIS. i.e I want a separate forms auth cookie/ticket for LoginWeb and a separate one for AdminWeb. But LoginWeb should also be able to issue the ticket for AdminWeb. (See the function above called SetAuthenticationTicket()). That is the one which issues the ticket for AdminWeb with the same Forms Name.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion about that. I'm not sure that can be done without some special single-sign-on code.